Sum up values from a vector until values from another vector are reached
I have two vectors. The first one contains values representing the annual energy demand. It has a length of 22 which represents 22 years. The second one is much larger and contains energy yield values in descending order.
Here is some code for reproduction:
# create demand vector
demand.vec <- c(427839, 408392, 388944, 369497.652793, 350050, 330603, 311155, 291708, 272261, 252814, 233366, 213919, 
                194472, 175025, 155577, 136130, 116683, 97236,  77788,  58341,  38894, 19447)

# create yield vector
set.seed(10)
yield.vec <- sort(runif(n = 10500, min = 800, max = 950), decreasing= T)

The goal is now for each year to sum up as many values as needed from yield.vec to reach at least the energy demand for the respective year. This means that for the first year, so many values from yield.vec should be summed up that 427839 is reached. In the second year from the remaining values of yield.vec the values should be summed up so that 408392 is reached and so forth.
As output I would need a vector with the resulting achieved annual energy yields and ideally also a vector that shows which values of the yield.vec were used for the respective years. So for the first year the value would be 428011.69755 since it is the result of sum(yield.vec[1:452]) and larger than demand.vec[1]. In this case the first value of the second output vector would be 452 since as many values were needed. The second achieved value would be 409118.77503, the result of sum(yield.vec[453:887]) which is larger than 408392. So the second value of the second output vector would be 435 since as many values were needed and so forth.
Any body with an idea?

To get the indices of the yield vector
tmp <- sapply(cumsum(demand.vec),\(x){which.max(x<=cumsum(yield.vec))})
 [1]  452  887 1303 1700 2079 2439 2780 3101 3402 3683 3944 4184 4403 4601 4777 4931 5064 5175
[19] 5264 5331 5376 5398

To get the difference from the previous result you could do
> c(tmp[1],diff(tmp))
 [1] 452 435 416 397 379 360 341 321 301 281 261 240 219 198 176 154 133 111  89  67  45  22


You can use findInterval + cumsum
> findInterval(cumsum(demand.vec), cumsum(yield.vec)) + 1
 [1]  452  887 1303 1700 2079 2439 2780 3101 3402 3683 3944 4184 4403 4601 4777
[16] 4931 5064 5175 5264 5331 5376 5398


Thanks ThomasIsCoding, that it what I was looking for. Especially findInternal is a really handy thing. user2974951 just added the part with the number of values for the respective years, which is something that was also required.
